# How to reuse code for singleton object in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, singleton

I got trouble when design class for my project. Currently, we developed 2 projects with the same structure but have some differences inside.

At project A, I have class `ACore` that includes `class AConfiguration, AEquipmentManager`. And I made an instance for object `ACore` that at everywhere in project, i can use: `Acore.AConfiguration.XYZ` (XYZ is method or property of `AConfiguration` class) or `ACore.AEquipmentmanager.ABC`(ABC is method or property of `AEquipmentManager` class)

At project B, I still have same structure with project A (`BCore, BConfiguration, BEquipmentManager`). But `BConfiguration` has different with `AConfiguration` (because each project has different configuration) and `BEquipmentManager` also has different with `AEquipmentManager`.

I want to reuse code for class `ACore` and `BCore` because they have the same code (Initialize EquipmentManager, Initialize Configuration, Dispose EquipmentManager, Dispose Configuration,...). Now, I want to write a library `BaseCore` that have the same structure with `ACore` and `BCore` (there are 2 class `Configuration`, `EquipmentManager`, same Intialize function, Dispose function), and with specific project (like A project, B project, or even C, D project later) i can use `BaseCore` library class (for reuse code) and just implement `XEquipmentManager`, `XCofiguration` depend on each project.

What is the best way I should design in this case? Thank for sharing your idea.

Regards,
Hoa Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track,

But I would do it with interfaces:

- Implement Core class that uses class that implements IConfigurable.
- Make sure AConfiguration implements IConfigurable and all the
  relevant methods.

Alternativly you can do something like that:

- Implement Core class that uses Configuration class.
- Implement AConfiguration/BConfiguration that inherits from
  Configuration.
- Reference A and B to the same Core class and that's it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does AConfiguration and BConfiguration have the same set of methods with different implementations or do the set methods also differ? If the set of methods are the same you could do it with interfaces. You could define an interface for configuration and equipmentamanager. Then you just BaseCore using these interface. Then you can supply the specific implementation in the construction of BaseCore Something like this (leaving out the singleton stuff)

```
interface IConfiguration
{ 
    void somefunc();
}

interface IEquipmentManager
{
    void someOtherFunc();
}

class BaseCore
{
   private IConfiguration conf;
   private IEquipmentmanager eq;
   private BaseCore(){};

   public BaseCore(IConfiguration inConf, IEquipmentmanager inEq) :
          conf(inConf), eq(inEq)
  {
    conf.someFunc();
  }

}

class AConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
   public void someFunc()
   {
        do stuff!
   }

   public int intprop{get;set;}
}

class AEquipmentmanager : IEquipmentmanager
{
   public void someOtherFunc()
   {
        do stuff!
   }
}
```

Note you have to initialize an instance of AConfiguration and AEquipmentmanager. Before the construction of BaseCore like so

```
AConfiguration conf = new AConfiguration();
AEquipmentmanager   eq   = new AEquipmentmanager();
BaseCore base = new BaseCore(conf eq);
```

Alternatively you can simply create a BaseCore constructor that takes some enum to signify which implementation to you and then initialize an instance of the appropriate class in the BaseCore Constructor.

Alternatively you could possibly to it by implementing BaseCore with to Generic parameters and provide the the configuration and equipmentmanager implementation through these. You could still use the interfaces just the same but implement BaseCore with limits on the Generic arguments. BaseCore would look something like this:

```
class BaseCore<Configuration_type,Equipmentmanager_type>  
               where Configuration_type : IConfiguration, new() 
               where Equipmentmanager_type : IEquipmentmanager, new()
{
   public Configuration_type Configuration {get;};
   public Equipmentmanager_type Equipmentmanager {get;};

   BaseCore()
   {
      Configuration = new Configuration_type();
      Equipmentmanager   = new Equipmentmanager_type();
   }
}
```

This however puts the constraint on the types that they need a parameterless constructor. Initialization could supposedly be done afterwards though.

If you want to specialize your core for a specific configuration you can inherit from it like this

```
class Acore<Configuration_type,Equipmentmanager_type> :
BaseCore<Configuration_type,Equipmentmanager_type> 
    where Configuration_type : AConfiguration ,new()
    where Equipmentmanager_type : AEquipmentmanager, new()
{
    Acore() : base()
    {
        Configuration.intprop = 10;
    }

}
```

Note that i added a property on AConfiguration that is not accessible in BaseCore but is in ACore

Comment: Because Configuration is a class that include a lot of Property that Serializable from xml file, and at each project I want to use it by: ACore.Aconfiguration.PropertyA. So, if I use interface, I need to declare PropertyA in IConfiguration, but PropertyA is only available on project A, not in project B. If I only define PropertyA on AConfiguration, so I must parse value when I want to access propertyA because ACore.AConfiguration return a IConfiguration, not AConfiguration. I dont want to parse value because there are a lot of places in project access to property of Configuration.

Comment: I updated the example to include inheriting from BaseCore, restricting the generic parameters to AConfiguration and AEquipmentmanager